# Salesforce: How does one retrieve whether a layout field has been marked as required?

Tags: salesforce, soql

So this is weird, wondering if perhaps SFDC is just returning "wrong" information.

I'm working with layouts for an object, and in the interface I have set a field in the default layout (there are no other layouts) to "required".

But, when I retrieve this layout from the API, the field in question's "nillable" attribute is TRUE when it should be FALSE.

Does salesforce expect data like this to be retrieved from somewhere else? Regardless it seems the API is lying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API is not lying - the field is only required by that particular layout, not by the underlying system.

If you want it to truly be required, you need to set this attribute on the field itself.

Comment: huh, so the definition returned for the field within the layout is the system's.  Check.

Is the "required" option within the layout exposed anywhere else in the API that I just haven't found yet?

Comment: Not sure - I'd say it's tied to the layout only and you'll only find it within the definition of that layout - probably not accessible from the API.

Comment: Yeah seems that way, it's surprising though since we're building a generic UI that's supposed to represent what the user sees in SFDC as closely as possible. Maybe it's hiding somewhere else in the layout response. :/